# Swig Error when using C functions in Kotlin - two different errors

Tags: java, c, android-studio, kotlin, swig

I am using the following command using swig:

```
swig -java -includeall -package onescream.onescream compute_feature_set.i
```

The interface file is:

```
/* compute_feature_set.i */
 %module compute_feature_set
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "compute_feature_set.h"
%}

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "compute_feature_set.h"
```

I get the following errors:

```
compute_feature_set.h:17: Error: Unable to find 'stddef.h'
compute_feature_set.h:18: Error: Unable to find 'stdlib.h'
```

If I try an alternative swig command list:

```
swig -java compute_feature_set.i
gcc -c compute_feature_set.c compute_feature_set_wrap.c -I/Users/fas/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home/include -I/Users/fas/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home/include/darwin
gcc -shared compute_feature_set.o compute_feature_set_wrap.o -o libcompute_feature_set.so
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_b_fft", referenced from:
      _compute_feature_set in compute_feature_set.o
  "_binary_expand_op", referenced from:
      _compute_feature_set in compute_feature_set.o
  "_eml_find", referenced from:
      _compute_feature_set in compute_feature_set.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not sure what else to do, any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't usually want `-includeall`, since you are unlikely to want to wrap the endire stddef.h and stdlib.h library functions (and in general it wouldn't work anyway).

Use `-I<dir>` to include other include directories in the search path.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine but then I have the same issue afterwards, Using the gcc commands I get the error: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Comment: @FerasAS SWIG can only handle some basic I/O types without additional help.  If your APIs are more complicated than POD input parameters, expect errors.  Without seeing the header file I can't help further.  If there are compile time options you may need to specify them to `swig` with `-D`, including default defines that a compiler gives by default, like `_DEBUG` or `_WIN32`.

Comment: Thank you Mark, would you be willing to have a call and help me with this? My email is feras.alsaab@outlook.com. I am really stuck and would really appreciate the help.